# Largest number with two hands

Tags: formation-of-numbers

Pretty short one, really.
Given your two hands, what's the largest number you can represent?

Some example representations:

1 finger on each hand: that's 2.
2 fingers on one hand, and 3 on the other: that's 5.

Only rule is that, if you represent x, you should be able to represent all numbers smaller than x using the same method. No negative numbers, only zero and above.

Edit(4 Jan): Pretty impressive answers by everybody. I'd like to clarify this question, however: you'll need to represent each number in a manner that's clearly and easily distinguishable. For example, bending at an angle can be ambiguous - how will you tell apart a representation of a finger bent at 50* and at 55*? At most you could use a straight finger for one number and bent finger for another.

Comment: Message to downvoter: the answer is **not** 10.

Comment: I suppose the downvote is because of the ambiguity of the question...

Comment: I have to have some ambiguity. Otherwise I'd be giving the answer away. As I said, the only rule is that 0 to that number should be representable; no gaps.

Comment: So is my answer not the one you're looking for?

Comment: Your answer is a viable candidate, my answer was actually smaller. However, I want to wait, in case someone else has a better answer still.

Comment: The only way to go higher is to allow something more than 1/0 with your fingers. Eg fingers half up, or hand up vs hand down.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. However this is getting excessively complicated, so I'd have to say your answer still stands.

Comment: Print out a sheet of paper with an arbitrarily large list of numbers. Indicate a number by pointing to it. If the sheet isn't allowed, use an imaginary one.

Comment: This looks like an interesting puzzle, though you should place some reasonable limits - e.g. the representation should consist of just the fingers without reference to any external object.

Comment: @Lawrence IMO it would still not be interesting. If there are enough constraints, it is a very easy job to figure out how many states each hand can be in. It will still be more of a math Q than a puzzling one.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code It's perhaps an easy puzzle, but it would appear from the comments that counting in binary didn't occur to the OP. This alone should count as an aha moment. Also, most fingers have 3 segments (thumbs have 2), there are interesting features on palms, there are the backs of the hands, and there's the complication of needing pointers in some schemes, so there's enough scope for further aha moments.

Comment: I did have an 'aha' moment when I discovered that you could technically represent 36 numbers with just 10 fingers, rather than just 10(when you use hands to count), if you use a base 5 notation. There are indeed a lot of 'aha' answers in here. I just wanted to see how much people could take this concept further.

Comment: "Clearly distinguishable" is too vague.

Comment: @Deusovi Do you have a better wording I can use?

Comment: @cst It depends on what you're trying to say. You need precise requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have **4** fingers on each hand; all your fingers have **three joints** which can all be extended or collapsed(representing a 0 and a 1) independent of each other.

You now have 3 bits of binary information in one finger, but you gotta remember, you have **8** in total (8*3=24), so you have **24 binary bits** of information in your 8 fingers.

**So what's the greatest number you can represent with this system?** 111111111111111111111111(base 2)=16777215(base 10)

So using my system you could display over 16 million different numbers, in just 8 fingers, *but hang on*...

You have **5** fingers on each hand, but your thumbs act differently than your other fingers.  They only have **2 joints**, so that's another 4 bits of information to our already huge 24 bit number, we now have **28 bits** to work with.

**So what's the new highest number?**

1111111111111111111111111111(base 2)=268435455(base 10).

Wow- a silly 4 bits added to the end allow you to display **over 260 million different numbers**.

That's a lot of information from just 10 simple fingers, don't ya think?

Comment: You must have some remarkable fingers, if you can bend the first and third joint (but not the second) of your middle finger. Good answer, and welcome to puzzling!

Answer (score 4):

**Something around 2,500,000,000,000,000.**

If we imagine a plane an arbitrarily far but non-infinite distance in front of me, I can point each of my fingers such that the ray extended from it will intersect that plane at a single point.  Let any parallel rays be considered - for this purpose - to be hitting the same point.  Based on this, I can point my ten fingers to generate a set of dots in an arbitrary order in both the X and Y axes, with points possibly being equivalent along one or both axes.  I may also choose *not* to point with some or all of my fingers, generating smaller arbitrarily ordered sets of points.

---

This describes the following set of options:

If no points are the same, there are 10! ways of ordering along a single dimension = 3,628,800.

If a pair of points are the same, then there are 10 choose 2 = 45*9! orders.  If a triplet are the same, there are 10 choose 3 = 120 * 8! orders.  We continue this sequence on down for a total of (per wolfram Alpha):

sum_2^10binomial(10, X) (11-X)!+10! = 26,065,011

But then we have the cases where one set is already paired off and another set gets paired.  This is the same problem, but with (10 choose 2) * 8 choose from 2 up to 8 with a factorial on the end, noting that we need to divide the first case in half to avoid duplication.  This gives...

binomial(10, 2) sum_2^8binomial(8, X) (9-X)!-binomial(10, 2) binomial(8, 2)×(7!)/2 = 5,436,405

We do this again for 10 choose 3 * 7 choose from 2 up to 7 etc etc:

binomial(10, 3) sum_2^7binomial(7, X) (8-X)!-binomial(10, 3) binomial(7, 3)×(5!)/2 = 2,184,120

And so on and so forth, keeping in mind that this gets trickier as we have more than two clusters, since we get phrases like Bi(10,2)Bi(8,2)Bi(6,3).  We also get a bunch more from the cases where I only point with nine of my fingers (10*9!, plus a few more for each possible set of clusters), the ones where I only point with eight fingers, etc.  I can't do the math at 4:00 am, so I'll approximate that we are at about 50,000,000 total cases.  But this is just one axis - we can do the same on the other axis, for a total of ~ 50,000,000^2 = 2,500,000,000,000,000 distinct situations.  Index them and order to taste.

---

Old Answer

---

**268,435,455**

If I have my fingers extended, each could reasonably touch any finger or (with some effort) combination of fingers on the other hand. Thus we have five fingers, each with (1+5+10+10+5+1) possible finger combinations they could be touching for a product of 32^5 values. Further, each hand could be either side up, and above or below the other - that's 8 more per option - 8*(32^5), which is 2^28 = **268,435,456** options.  Some of these may be tricky to physically achieve, but they should all be possible. Pick your favorite ordering.

Comment: This is a remarkable answer, but unfortunately representation in this form is pretty difficult to interpret for somebody who's standing in front of you, for example.

Comment: @cst Since when was readability for someone *else* part of the requirements?

Comment: @Deusovi You're right, there was a communication gap. I have had to edit the question; it was attracting answers of the type that I wasn't looking for.

Answer (score 4):

**Any number!**

And you need only 1 finger.

Consider your straight index finger as the number $0$ and your completely bend finger as $x$ where $x$ is any number you like. Now measure the angle that your finger bend at one of the joints of that finger in comparison with the stretched finger and call it $a$. Now every other number is constructed by bending your index finger slightly less and measuring the angle that you bent it and call it $b$. and then your number is $\lceil {b \over a} \cdot x \rceil$.

Of course measuring this angle can only be up to some accuracy but that doesn't matter. The question is not how accurately you can know what the number is but if you can represent every number, and this is true

Comment: You did put me in a soup there...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your fingers can only be up or down, there are only 1024 combinations. Using simple binary you can do all the numbers from 0 to 1023. Which would make 1023 the biggest number.

Comment: Now add in up/left/right/down as an aditional 2 bits per hand, and you have 16k, do the dame with angling it forward/backwards and you have 256k+

Answer (score 0):

[$g_5$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham's_number#Magnitude), as in the notation of Graham's number.

[image]

Comment: I'm intrigued to hear how you plan to represent all the numbers less than this as well.

Comment: @Zerris, d'oh, misread the challenge.  I will leave this up in case someone much smarter than me thinks of a way.